# Command for loading postgres through docker?

Tags: docker

Does anyone know the command for loading postgres through docker? Here is the recommended command on [their documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h some-postgres -U postgres
```

Forgive the naive question, how do you find what values for "some-network" are supposed to be and what values "some-postgres" is supposed to be?

Comment: Is there any reason why this question is downvoted? It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. My command was technically correct, but postgres takes a few seconds to load the server. The postgres client can't connect to the server until this happens! These commands worked for on my system:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password  -it --rm postgres

docker ps
(get container_id from this)

docker exec -it container_id  psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, each flag has a own meaning in the `docker run` command.

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h some-postgres -U postgres
```

`-i`: Keep STDIN open even if not attached

`-t`: Allocate a pseudo-TTY

`--rm`: Automatically remove the container when it exits

`--network`: Connect a container to a network. You can ignore this if you are running a standalone postgress container or you can use `host` mode if you want the container to use host networking. For more information and modes. Check below article.

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/network/

`psql -h some-postgres -U postgres` : Final command you are passing to postgres

Comment: I want to use the psql command in the docker container, not on my host. When I do a:
docker run -it --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -v /home/steve/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.5.21 psql -h localhost -p 567

I get the following error: "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Comment: As postgress will take some time to start, your command will fail at the first attempt for few minutes for sure. Another bit, your port mentioned above is wrong. It should be `5432` instead of `567`

Answer (score 0):

network in docker is used for interconnection between your containers which are needed to be communicated. If you only want postgres on docker you can ignore the network. `some-network` is the network name you want to use generally which can be listed by `docker network ls` command. `some-postgres` is the ip of the host server you want to run a container upon. You can run postgres on docker by following command

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name containername -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=yourpassword -d postgres
```

Here you can set the port, name password and `-d` is used for `daemon` mode and in the end, name of the image you want to use for postgres. This command will pull a postgres image from docker hub and set a running container for you. and more if you want to run psql inside the container you can connect to container ip which can be found by

```
docker inspect container_id
```

then run the command

```
psql -h host_serverip -U postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `docker run` or the elevated permissions this requires just to access the database.  Install the PostgreSQL client on your host if you haven't already.  If you started the database with

```
docker run -p 5678:5432 ... postgres
```

or an equivalent Docker Compose `ports:` option, then you can access the database with

```
psql -h localhost -p 5678
```

using the first port number.

This `psql` command runs on the host and thinks it's talking to a remote database.  PostgreSQL `COPY` commands and the `psql -f` option will use the file system where the client is running; if you're using `psql` directly, that's your current host directory that you can `ls`, and you won't have to do extra tricks to make the host content available to a client running in a container.

Comment: I would like to access psql from within the docker container. But if I do it, it gives this error: "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Comment: You need to know the network name and container name you were asking about in the question; those should be the `docker run --net ... --name ...` options from when you started the container.