# How load psql through docker?

Tags: docker

I am trying to load psql through docker. I went through the instructions on the official dockerhub page: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

The official command in the documentation is here:

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
```

I replaced "some-network" with various network_ids and they all didn't
work. The following error I get is this:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server:
>   Connection refused    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and
>   accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I read through the documentation, so I assume this must be some sort of error. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: The command you had in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62126627/10008173) will work better – you need to give the server container's `--name` to the `psql -h` option, not `127.0.0.1` (which will refer to the psql client container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description in the documentation in not so clear.
As it starts the server and immediately try to connect to it.
The client pqsl is running too early and fails to connect.

If you just want to "play with postgres" i suggest doing this in two steps.

```
 # docker run -d --rm  \
 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD='trust' \
postgres

43319e274a61394f111afb8a43b9bdfd4a46795ea5c8f9c78be4698135e45b33 <-container id 

# docker exec -it \
    <continer id> \
    psql -U postgres

\\psql (12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: Yes, this did it! The server couldn't load fast enough for psql to work. psql has to "wait" for the sever to come back on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`--network some-network` is an option to add the container you are trying to run to a network, you can just omit this option for simple docker usage.

The command you are executing will create a container from `PostgreSQL` and try to use `psql` client utility to connect to `PostgreSQL` server, so you need a running Postgres server, to make it work just follow these steps:

**step one**: run a container:

```
docker pull postgres && docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

**step two**: connect to the container you already have `PostgreSQL` server running and to do so you have to get the ip address for this container using [`inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) (note that we are specifying container name `some-postgres` we created in the previous step):

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' some-postgres
```

**step three**: this will print out the IP address for the container that we want to
    connect to, then run this

```
docker run -it --rm postgres psql -U postgres -h IP_ADDRESS
```

this will prompt you to insert password (in our case `mysecretpassword`)

---

**This is not really an efficient way to connect, so what I suggest you do after step one, is to just run [`exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)**, which allow you do connect/run `psql` and connect to already exsiting container without the need to get all the network options.

```
docker exec -it some-postgres psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Ok, this answer was right. However, in my case "localhost" can be used for the ipaddress, you don't have to derive it from "docker inspect". The solution was waiting a few seconds and then issuing the "docker exec" command that you listed.